# validation user input in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to validate the user's input by checking the length of their input string. Right now the code will validate if the user's input whatever is string or integer. But I need help with validate the length of their input string and give them an error if the length of the input string is less than 2.

```
const handleText = (event) => {
    let letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if (event.target.value.match(letters)) {
        setText(event.target.value);
    }else
        setText("error");
}

return(


<div>
<TextField onChange = {handleText}  label={"Name"}/>
            {text}
</div>


);


}
```

Comment: did you try using `.length` ?

Comment: How do you use .length in this solution?

Comment: `event.target.value.length < somenumber` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this code will help. You can play with it on this link [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-euclid-75nge?file=/src/App.js) i created. You can validate length through onSubmit event by using the length property.

Comment: This is what I expected. Thank you!!

Comment: If it answered your question you can mark it as accepted answer for helping stackoverflow community.